# Using SELECT DISTINCT to retrieve nearly identical array values in PGSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, distinct

In an app that I am currently developing users are allowed to locations identified, amongst other things by their latitude/longitude coordinates. The location entries end up in a Postgres table.

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."destis" (
 "id" integer DEFAULT nextval('destis_id_seq') NOT NULL,
 "author" integer NOT NULL,
 "einzig" character varying(12) NOT NULL,
 "lang" character varying(2) NOT NULL,
 "title" character varying(24) NOT NULL,
 "xtent" real[] DEFAULT '{0,0,0,0}' NOT NULL,
 "center" real[] DEFAULT '{0,0}' NOT NULL,
 "touchdown" real[] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT "destis_einzig" UNIQUE ("einzig")
) WITH (oids = false);
```

The above is a simplified version of that table - I had skipped irrelevant field entries.  I want to run a periodic CRON job that updates the weather data (stored on Redis) at each DISTINCT location as identified by the `center` column in each row of this table.

The issue here is with that word - **DISTINCT**.  In a typical scenario I could have two or more destination entries that are at nearly the same location.  e.g.

```
center = {5.87083,49.7784611}
center = {5.87099,49.7784703}
center = {5.87021,49.778452}
```

For all practical purposes there is only one latitude/longitude pair here {5.871,49.778} for which I need to launch an external API call to fetch the current weather.

The question here is how do I do this directly in SQL?  While I could quite easily fetch all `center` array values as JSON, compare them for *near equality* in PHP and then fetch weather for just a few distinct locations I cannot but help wonder if there isn't a way to simply run a query that returns distinct {lat,long} values after rounding them to three places of decimal.  I have on occasion, used `SELECT DISTINCT...`  but I have no idea how/whether I can use this on an array field

Comment: Why do you store two locations if you know that they are *logically* identical?

Comment: Geographical identity is a context dependent thing.  For local weather two locations 1km apart generally have the same weather - barring highly local phenomena such as tornados,  But in many other ways thosee two locations will be different - demographics, facilities, shopping....

Comment: So, they *are* different. (I know: it is data entered by the users). You probably want the *closest* point. In POSTGIS that would probably need st_dist_within() and/or st_distance().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array to an array of rounded values using something like this:

```
array[round(center[1]::numeric, 2), round(center[2]::numeric, 2)]::real[] as center
```

I would probably create a function so that I don't have to repeat this expression over and over again.